# Spring-Boot : 400 Bad request error even when parameter is present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-status-code-400, bad-request

In the following method there are two parameters `childFile` and `file`, I run this call through postman but it gives me 400 Bad Request error when I check the logs it says that parameter `childFile` is not present, I attach code, error and postman screenshot please tell me what is the issue

[image: Postman Call]

**Controller**

```
@Transactional
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "api/addchild",produces="application/json")
    public  ResponseEntity<?> child(Authentication authentication,
            @RequestParam(value="childFile") String childFile, @RequestParam(value="file") MultipartFile file) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Child child;
        try {
            child=mapper.readValue(childFile, Child.class);
            Child createdChild=childRepo.save(child);
            if(createdChild!=null)
            {
             childService.createChildPhoto(file, createdChild.getId());
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok("child created");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Child can not be created , please check your headers and string body again.");   
    }
```

**Logs**

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name] with value ["childFile"

{
           "id": 0,
                  "firstName": "Abeer",
                "lastName": "Hashmi",
                "gender": "Male",
                "dateOfBirth": "1999-02-11",
                "detail": null,
                "emergencyNumber": "03001111115",
                "medicalCondition": false,
                "medicalConditionDescription": null,
                "enabled": true
}

------WebKitFormBoundary3t9AJTMgmU7MV4da
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="child3.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
[![org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'childFile' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:198) ~\[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:109) ~\[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~\[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) \[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) \[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) \[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) \[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) \[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) \[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) \[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) \[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) \[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) \[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) \[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23\]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) \[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) \[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23\]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) \[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23\]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) \[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23\]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) \[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23\]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) \[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23\]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) \[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23\]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) \[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) \[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) \[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE\]][1]][1]
```

Comment: add childFile in QueryParam and try.

Comment: In postman, try changing the content type of `childFile` from `Text` to `application/json`.. I doubt it won't make difference but I would like to see the error.

Comment: @harshavmb only two options available text or file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found a solution to this problem..The issue was with postman when I remove content-type header it works fine,Postman insert header by itself

Answer (score 1):

You are using form data with a simple request param, that's not how it works. If you are trying to send the json and file together, make sure "childFile"'s content type is "application/json" and receive it by request body with annotation @RequestPart, and mapping produces should be "multipart/form-data", then it will do the job.

Comment: Now it gives the following error 

    
`Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/json"`

Comment: Maybe the postman cannot do what i wanted, it's not a mixed stream. Actually, i just set the content-type in the header to 'undefined', but the blob of 'childFile' is application/json, it's part of the form data, this is what i would do in my code:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', yourfile);
fd.append('childFile', new Blob([JSON.stringify(fileInfo)], {
    type: "application/json"
}));
```

I donnot know what exactlly the postman can do.